# Midnight Commander (mc) normal "+" and "-" keys working as those on numpad

Tags: keyboard, mc

When I press normal "+" or "-" on keyboard, they work as I'd press those on numpad - mc is popping the dialog for selecting/deselecting files. So its impossible to type any command that contains "+" or "-" (like eg. "ls -al").

This happens on my laptop (which doesn't have numpad), but also on standard ANSI keyboard connected with USB.
"Learning keys" in mc doesn't seem to help.
This is the same for Debian 9 and Debian testing (10).

Any idea why this is not working correctly?

*My mc version shows "3:4.8.21-1".*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me `+` and `-` open these dialogs only when the command line is empty. After I enter some non-special characters `+` and `-` are added to the command line.

To enter any special character at the command line press <kbd>Ctrl+q</kbd>: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> (or <kbd>-</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks for an answer, this workaround working for me too. What version is your mc?

Comment: 4.8.18 from Debian 9.